# How does a lambda replacing an Anonymous new Runnable() work?

Tags: java, lambda, runnable, anonymous-class

When you write an anonymous **Runnable** such as:

```
Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // do something
      }
});
```

IntelliJ suggests to replaces it with the following lambda:

```
Thread producer = new Thread(() -> {
       // do something
    }
});
```

which works just as fine.

How exactly does this work? In particular:

1. The constructor used is still `Thread(Runnable target)`, but nothing in the lambda appears to indicate that it's a Runnable.
2. Why `@Override public void run()` is suddenly not needed any more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your anonymous class has only one method you can implement it as a lambda expression. What you pass as the lambda here is the implementation of the `run` method. Lambda expressions let you express instances of single-method classes more compactly.